# Selenium cannot find text box

Tags: firefox, automated-tests, selenium-ide

I am trying to record my test on a major web based application in Firefox using Selenium IDE. There are some textboxes in one web page where I want to input some values. The problem is whenever I run the test to record it, the id of the textbox elements change in every session. I used xpath to locate the textboxes but the xpath just gives me the same element id. Can anyone tell me how do I go about locating textboxes?? I have also looked into the source code and nothing else is unique among the 4 textboxes except the id which changes on every run. Thanks

Comment: "nothing else is unique among the 4 textboxes " Even the order on the page isn't the same from run to run? Nothing in their parents/ancestors can be used to distinguish them? Can you post a simplied page HTML so people can see more detail?

Comment: Paul is right. At least one thing is unique about each box: it's relative position (and I'll bet it doesn't change).  You can use that in an XPath: "//input[@type='textarea' and positon() = 2]" will match the second <INPUT TYPE=TEXTAREA> on the page.

Answer (score 0):

try to locate text box by name
Eg.text box name is To then script will be

```
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>name=to</td>
    <td>testt</td>
</tr>
```